# combine a linechart with a barchart

Tags: charts, javafx

I'm trying to make a barchart combined with a linechart using a pane, but it doesn't work. It only shows me the linechart and not the barchart with it, and I don't know why. Can you help me.

```
    Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setScene(
        new Scene(
            layerCharts(
               createBarChart()
                    ,createLineChart()
            )
        )
    );
    stage.show();
}

private NumberAxis createYaxis() {
    final NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis(0, 21, 1);
    axis.setPrefWidth(35);
    axis.setMinorTickCount(10);

    axis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(axis) {
        @Override public String toString(Number object) {
            return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        }
    });

    return axis;
}

private BarChart<String, Number> createBarChart() {
    final BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), createYaxis());
    setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
    chart.getData().addAll(
        new XYChart.Series(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new XYChart.Data("Jan", 2),
                new XYChart.Data("Feb", 10),
                new XYChart.Data("Mar", 8),
                new XYChart.Data("Apr", 4),
                new XYChart.Data("May", 7),
                new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5),
                new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9),
                new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17),
                new XYChart.Data("Dec", 10)
            )
        )
    );
    return chart;
}

private LineChart<String, Number> createLineChart() {
    final LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), createYaxis());
    setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    chart.getData().addAll(
        new XYChart.Series(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1),
                new XYChart.Data("Feb", 2),
                new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5),
                new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3),
                new XYChart.Data("May", 2.5),
                new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                new XYChart.Data("Sep", 6.5),
                new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13),
                new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10),
                new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20)
            )
        )
    );
    return chart;
}

private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    chart.setAnimated(false);
}

private StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<String, Number> ... charts) {
    for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
        configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
    }

    StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
    stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);

    return stackpane;
}

private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
    chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
    chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
    chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false); 
   chart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.5); -fx-background-radius: 10;");
    //chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("StyleSheet1.scss").toExternalForm());
}
```

my css sheet

```
.chart-plot-background { 
-fx-background-color: transparent; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you stacking charts? Is it possible to place all the data into a line chart?

Comment: i want to make a climate chart

Comment: I guess the code source is from: [Stacking charts in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788117/stacking-charts-in-javafx).  It looks like you modified the code to not use the attached stylesheet and use an inline style - however you can't do that, the styles need to be defined in a stylesheet as demonstrated in the original example code.