# How to add line series in stacked bar chart in javafx

Tags: javafx, stackedbarseries

I have a stacked bar chart with only two series data. Now i want to add two series line dataset into the same chart. How to do it in javafx.

Comment: You probably have to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788117/stacking-charts-in-javafx

Comment: I did that but the two graphs are not overlapping and the range also differs. How to get the range of y-axis dynamically?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).